# VBA Excel Worksheet_Change prevent update

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible for `worksheet_change` to not process the pending/already happened user update by exiting the sub should a condition not be met? I have a logging system and do not want the user to delete more than one cell at a time, since my code handles one-cell-at-a-time updates - Eventually the code should be improved to allow this. But for the meantime:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

 If Selection.Count > 1 Then
   MsgBox ("please delete items one at a time")
   Exit Sub
 End If
```

This displays the msgbox ok, but proceeds with the deletion of the contents of all cells in the selection, should multiple cells be selected. The deleted contents then gets missed by the logging system.

Ok, trying to get to "final destination" in response to @Gary's Student answer since it isn't really illegal to delete multiple cells.

Partially using @binil 's solution gets me to this pseudocode but I am not good enough to complete it (the cells in the range may be non-contiguous)

```
Dim theoldvals As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer

for each c in the oldvals
Sheets("log").ActiveCell.Value = "OLD value" = oldvals(c)
         .ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = "NEW value" = Target(c) ' where c is the corresponding cell/index in the target range
Next c

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set theoldvals = Target
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have another sheet (set `Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden` so users can't just show it through the regular unhiding process) that is a clone of your sheet then. Then any time you are in the `Worksheet_Change` event you can check your validation conditions. if your conditions fail you grab the old value from your clone sheet, if you pass validation then you write to your regular sheet like normal and *duplicate that write to your clone sheet.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent something after it has already happened.  However:

```
If Selection.Count > 1 Then
   MsgBox ("please delete items one at a time")
   ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
 End If
```

will prevent the illegal changes from being saved.

Comment: Then focus your efforts on getting to the "Final Destination."